# System freezes randomly

Tags: freeze, thinkpad, mint

**My system**

Thinkpad E580, Model 20KS001JGE
Dual boot with pre-installed Windows 10

**My problem**

Ubuntu Mint 18.04 freezes randomly after 0 - 10 minutes of usage. Sometimes even at the login screen.

**What i tried before **

Same problem with Linux Mint 18.3: Installed all available updates, installed latest available kernel (4.17), re-installed MINT twice, installed Ubuntu instead of MINT. I bought the laptop three months ago and never had any trouble while using the pre-installed Windows 10.

Anyone else with the same system and/or an idea to solve it?

Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Sorry: Ubuntu MATE, not Mint.

Comment: How much RAM? How nuch SWAP? Watch the logs with `journalctl --follow`

Comment: 8 GB RAM, 8.4 GB SWAP.

Comment: And nothing special in the logs. It simply crashes, no log the second(s) before.